# ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

hello I found a warning like this when installing the npm package

what is the problem and how to solve it?

```
PS D:\Gogomall\GogoMobile\Project\Mobile\GoMobileApp> npm install @react-navigation/native 
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN   react-shallow-renderer@"16.14.1" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN     react-shallow-renderer@"16.14.1" from react-native@0.69.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native
```

Comment: Add legacy-peer-deps flag like `npm install your-package-name --legacy-peer-deps` which ignores peer dependencies.